# Convert Robot Framework xPath to Selenium Python equivalent.

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to convert xpath in robot to python code. I wanted the below xpath in Robot to be converted to python code

This works in Robot:

```
xpath=(//th[@class="picker-switch"])[2]
```

I have tried in python

```
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[@class='picker-switch'][2]")
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//th[@class='datepicker-switch'][2]"}
```

and

```
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[@class='picker-switch']")[2]
```

That caused:

```
'WebElement' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: "Don't work" is quite a broad area. Can you provide us with the error message?

Comment: I have added the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It start working when I  encased the xpath statement with brackets `(...)`:

```
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//th[@class='picker-switch'])[2]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It failed, as what you have put in the first python attempt was not the same xpath as in RF ;).

In the original xpath the expression is surrounded with brackets `(expression)`, and then the index. Which reads - find all elements matching the expression, and return the second one.

Without the brackets it is - find all `th` with that class, which are the 2nd child of their parents element - quite different :)

For the record, the corrected second python attempt should be

```
self._driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//th[@class='picker-switch']")[1]
```

[`find_elements_by_xpath`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) will return all elements matching the expression as a list, and `[1]` will return the 2nd element in that list - python's lists are zero-based (start from index 0), while xpath's - one-based.